# Uploading media

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm building client/server app. However I don't know to make the following:
I have implemented registration through IPhone with NSConnection, But also would like to upload a picture and video.
I want to know the controll which allows to get media from IPhone (like path or smth) and what settings should I add to my NSConnection to enable media uploading.
Also I think something should be added in Php script to enable uploading media files.

Thanks a lot for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSData* resourceToUpload = ... // setting data to upload
NSMutableURLRequest* request = ... // HTTP method is POST
[request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:resourceToUpload];
// sending request
```

My advise is also to use some network framework e.g. AFNetworking.